# Google Forms - hybrid ranking/checklist question

Tags: google-forms

I would like to create a ranking question, which only allows one selection per column. On the same row of each object being ranked, I would like the ability to add additional options that don't affect the rankings. I've added a picture that I think makes it clear.

[image: Hybrid options grid]

Is this possible? Is there an add-on that already exists? Do you think it can be done with code?

Answer (score 1):

Google Forms doesn't handle "hybrid" grids and add-ons can't handle the Google Forms respond view, the only are able to add features to the Google Forms edit view.